# Python FitBit Library. "Authorization Error: Invalid authorization token type"

Tags: python, api, fitbit

I'm having trouble accessing FitBit's API using the fitbit library in Python ... Does anyone have any suggestions for a fix?

```
import fitbit

consumer_key = '22AA4K'
consumer_secret = '931439b475f0b1c1bf610f093ae0b16b'
access_token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIyMkJSNEsiLCJzdWIiOiI0WU5HM1EiLCJpc3MiOiJGaXRiaXQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZM4iLCJzY29wZXMiOiJyc29jIHJzZXQgcmFjdCBybG9jIHJ3ZWkgcmhyIHJwcm8gcm51dCByc2xlIiwiZXhwIjoxNTg5MzgzMDQ5LCJpYPQiOjE1ODg3ODY3ODV9.kDZFp6CExpgQDR0vCt3ZMrT5bM5QSK9419RkMTqhY1Q'

unauth_client = fitbit.Fitbit(consumer_key, consumer_secret,
                              access_tokenn=access_token,
                              refresh_token=None)

unauth_client.food_units()
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Test_16.03.20/Test.py", line 11, in <module>
    unauth_client.food_units()
  File "C:\Users\venv\Test_16.03.20\lib\site-packages\fitbit\api.py", line 867, in food_units
    return self.make_request(url)
  File "C:\Users\venv\Test_16.03.20\lib\site-packages\fitbit\api.py", line 256, in make_request
    response = self.client.make_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\venv\Test_16.03.20\lib\site-packages\fitbit\api.py", line 99, in make_request
    exceptions.detect_and_raise_error(response)
  File "C:\Users\venv\Test_16.03.20\lib\site-packages\fitbit\exceptions.py", line 82, in detect_and_raise_error
    raise HTTPUnauthorized(response)
fitbit.exceptions.HTTPUnauthorized: Authorization Error: Invalid authorization token type

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: you shouldn't show your key, secret, and token here!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the warning. This is just an example key, so it will not work.

Comment: The Python fitbit library uses oAuth (1.0) authentication while FitBit's API uses OAuth 2.0 authentication. Could that be the issue her?